# Update some fields of a document in Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update some fields of a document in Firestore. Below is the code. But it's not working. Please help me!

```
@IBAction func btnGoBack(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if usersPaid != true {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document("m8FdPX4zVJ77ZodP8h0T").updateData([
            "titlePage": titlePageOnChanged!,
            "endPage": endPageOnChanged!,
            "pageNumber": pageNumberOnChanged!,
            "passCode": passCodeOnChanged!
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully updated")
            }
        }
    }
    
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBack", sender: nil)

}
```

Below is a screenshot of firestore.

[a screenshot of firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF81O.png)

Comment: Can you share your firestore structure pic?

Comment: Please, add the error/output that is being printed. Also check `usersPaid *==* true`

Comment: @Juancki Thank you for your reply. The" usersPaid = true" was supposed to be "usersPaid != true". I corrected that. Can you help me with how to adding the error/output that is being printed? I guessed that given the code, if there is any error, it should be printed :)

Comment: @Picode I added the structure of my firestore. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @DavidGoo check my answer please.

Comment: Two things. 1) Please do not use links. Include the image in the question. If the link breaks then future readers will not understand the question.  2) MOST IMPORTANT. Your performSegue will be called BEFORE your data is updated in Firestore. That may be ok but be aware it takes time for that update to happen and code is faster than the internet.

Comment: Also, please note that if you're trying to update the document as shown in the question "m8FdPX4zVJ77ZodP8h0T", what's shown in the screenshot is NOT that document. The screenshot documentId is "uDo1..."

Answer (score 1):

You must change your `document id` to your `Firestore document id` from picture:

```
document("uDo1jHFTbMJSq4V5146X")
```

and generally,

you code must be like `db.collection("users").document(yourUserId).updateData`

Writing `yourUserId` automatically is better than manual :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
db.collection("users").document("userId").updateData([
```

Specifically here:

```
document("userId")
```

`"userId"` as a string is not a document id. The document id according to the photo is uDo1....

Comment: Yes. that is like "m8FdPX4zVJ77ZodP8h0T". I don't think that this is the problem :) Thanks!

Comment: What was ```"userId"``` for then?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the code below:

```
        db.collection("users")
        .whereField("userEmail", isEqualTo: userEmail!)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")
            } else if querySnapshot!.documents.count > 0 {
                let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
                document!.reference.updateData([
                    "titlePage": titlePageOnChanged!,
                    "endPage": endPageOnChanged!,
                    "pageNumber": pageNumberOnChanged!,
                    "passCode": passCodeOnChanged!
                ])
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the question. It may 'work' but is not the right solution. The question asks how to update a specific document "m8FdPX4zVJ77ZodP8h0T" with data. This code queries for a document with an email address, then takes the first one returned (which may NOT be the correct one) and updates the data. e.g. if you have 5 documents with the same email, this query could return any one of them, not necessarily the correct one.